# How could I have a button display innerHTM text once it's clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How could I make a button to respond by displaying the content inside saved in local storage

```
//store value once entered
 localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(ids1.value);
 let local = localStorage.getItem('store');

let button = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
let newd = document.getElementsByClassName('newd');


let parog = document.createElement('p');
parog.innerHTML = local;
parog.style.display = 'none';

if(local !== null){ 

    button.addEventListener('click', () => { 
        newd[0].appendChild(parog.style.display = 'block');
       
    })
}
```

What I get is addEventListener is not a function. Any idea on how to get ti display id the condition is met

Comment: Could you add your HTML code here? We really don't want to guess what `.button` is. Also, what is the return value you expect from `parog.style.display = 'block'`?

Comment: @InSync I created an input  object that stores the value in localstorage I can see it display on `parog.style.display = 'block'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements.

Either do:

```js
button[0].addEventListener('click', () => { 
  newd[0].appendChild(parog.style.display = 'block');
})
```

or

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.button');
```

(This is assuming your buttons have the class `button`. If you're trying to query for all `button` elements, use `document.getElementsByName("button")` or `document.querySelector("button")`)